# exit function doesn't work with threading method

Tags: python, multithreading, exit

I need some help with my code
I used to use `exit()` function in python but today I tried to use threading library
This my code:

```
import time
import threading

ts = time.time()
ts_after = ts + 5


def printit():
    global ts_after
    threading.Timer(1.0, printit).start()
    ts1 = time.time()
    if int(ts1) >= int(ts_after):
        print("11")
        exit()
    else:
        pass


printit()
```

it's work very well and `print("11")` also work but the `exit()` after the print doesn't work and keep printing 11

Comment: ``import sys``?

Comment: What should this code do in the first place? Close the current thread on `int(ts1) >= int(ts_after)`? Or close the application? Or something else?

Comment: You have to use `sys.exit()`. And even if you do, your code endlessly starts new threads. You should start the new thread *outside* the function that is called in the thread.

Comment: i tried import sys and didn't work, and this code make test for student after n time it will close

Comment: you are creating multiple threads - infinite to be accurate. if exit() works it only closes one thread not all threads

Answer (score 0):

Using the `cancel()` method on the `Timer` instance seems to produce your desired behaviour:

```
import time
import threading

ts = time.time()
ts_after = ts + 5


def printit():
    global ts_after
    my_thread = threading.Timer(1.0, printit)
    my_thread.start()
    ts1 = time.time()
    if int(ts1) >= int(ts_after):
        print("11")
        my_thread.cancel()
    else:
        pass


printit()
```

The `cancel()` method simply stops the `Timer` instance before it has begun. Note that it is probably a good idea to extend this code so that it can also quit `Timer` objects that have already started.